# Unable to Connect ERPNext with Node-RED through REST API

Tags: docker, rest, containers, node-red, erpnext

I am trying to establish a connection with ERPNext on Node-RED through REST API but in Node-RED I am getting "No Response from Server". The Node-RED Flow I am using:

[image]

My function node:

[image]

My http response node:

[image]

Both my ERPNext and Node-RED are running on Docker under a same network bridge. The IP address that I have used is the IP address of the ERPNext Docker Container.

The ports I am running ERPNext and Node-RED are on 8000 and 1880 respectively.

The error from Node-RED debug is:

> {"_msgid":"c3f7ab18.91e928","payload":"Error: ETIMEDOUT :
> [http://172.19.0.8:8000/api/resource/Item","topic":"","method":"GET","headers":{"Authorization":"token](http://172.19.0.8:8000/api/resource/Item%22,%22topic%22:%22%22,%22method%22:%22GET%22,%22headers%22:%7B%22Authorization%22:%22token)
> f5a1ab34ac4db01:bb0516b2d3c1016","Accept":"application/json","Content-Type":"application/json"},"url":"http://172.19.0.8:8000/api/resource/Item","statusCode":"ETIMEDOUT"}

I have tried using localhost:8000 on Node-RED but that did not work. I have tried using the same thing in Python. It works in python however as shown:

[image]

The code used in VSCode for the REST connection:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/api/resource/Item
Authorization: token f5a1ab34ac4db01:bb0516b2d3c1016
```

The output from VSCode attempting the REST connection:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2023 17:12:37 GMT
Server: nginx/1.21.6
Set-Cookie: sid=Guest; Expires=Thu, 16-Mar-2023 17:12:37 GMT; Path=/,system_user=yes; Path=/,full_name=Guest; Path=/,user_id=Guest; Path=/,user_image=; Path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Connection: close

{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "001"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want it to work with Node-RED and it should. I am just stuck. Help much appreciated.

Comment: The only error you've shared (the status under the HTTP-Request node) implies the ERPNext server never responded. What do you see in the logs from both systems? (p.s. `localhost` will always point to the container making the request, so is 100% not the right value for NR to reach another container)

Comment: Also it would probably be useful to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75724999/edit) to show what ports are mapped to what values (post text, not a screenshot)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have added more information now. I have used the ERPNext Docker container's IP Address in Node-RED but that isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the Node-RED issue by using the Docker Container networked bridge's gateway IP Address. The Node-RED container and ERPNext container are under a networked bridge with gateway address 172.18.0.1. Using this successfully created the REST connection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).